# RP3 as Nodered+Deluge server and Nginx configuration

Tags: raspbian, networking, deluge, nodered, nginx

I'm running RP3 as Nodered and Deluge (torrent) server, by default I can access Nodered via http://host_ip:1880 and Deluge via http://host_ip:8112 but now I installed Nginx (I'm newbie with it) then configure Nginx as reverse proxy to by pass port and use https (if my word is right??)

I edited /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file so now I can access Nodered via https://host_ip (no port):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key; 
  ssl_verify_depth 3;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256";

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1880/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Now I like to do with Deluge too, my idea is setting Nginx to access Deluge via https://host_ip/torrent (or any path name) but I really don't know how to set it work. Can anyone help me or saying that it's impossible so I could stop thinking about it :) Thanks

Comment: `location /torrent { proxy_pass http://localhost:8112/; ... etc}`

Comment: I tried it already but when I access https://host_ip/torrent what I only see is correct page title (Deluge: Web UI 1.3.10) but there is no content on page

Comment: I found solution on Deluge page [link](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/WebUI/ReverseProxy)

Comment: Can you please make a short answer to explain how you solved the question? It may help others looking for a solution and will finalize the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I added these lines in Nginx config file

```
location /torrent {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8112/;
proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base "/torrent/";
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

After restart nginx service you can access Deluge web UI via https://host_ip/torrent

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.